# windows os: vagrant ssh dont' work with git

Tags: windows, git, ssh, vagrant

I'm trying to use `vagrant ssh` in windows console, but it don't work.
Vagrant is correctly installed, and i've installed also Git for windows.
Also, correct `path` is installed in the system environment, using

```
setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin"
```

and i can see the path add-on in the console via `path` and also in the windows system environment.

But when i'm use `vagrant ssh` in the windows console it give me the usual error:

> `ssh` executable not found in any directories in the %PATH% variable.
>   Is an SSH client installed? Try installing Cygwin, MinGW or Git, all
>   of which contain an SSH client. Or use your favorite SSH client with
>   the following authentication information shown below:
>
> Host: 127.0.0.1 Port: 2222 Username: vagrant Private key:
>   `C:/vagtest/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key`

If i digit path in console, i have the correct path with git location, but it is useless.

If i digit

```
 set PATH=%PATH%;C:\C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin
```

the command 
    `vagrant ssh` run, but obviusly when i close the console and reopen it, it don't run more.

I really don't understand what happen.

Comment: I think it can be useful to remarke that, if in windows console i digit git -h, it correctly runs. So the path is recognized, but for any reasons, vagrant don't capture the path if you don explicity digit set path .. in console.

Answer (score 1):

try ***>vagrant ssh*** from **Git Bash** window

Comment: The point is "why don't run in console?". i know there are other solutions, for example I have a working setup with putty, but the idea is to use the windows console for all operations, you know vagrant up ,  vagrant ssh , rail s , and a good windows editor on the shared directory.

Comment: All run now correctly reinstalling git in C:\Git instead than into \Program File (x86)\Git.

Comment: @IdoTraini, This is really a very good info; i will try the same in my system. Thanks.

Comment: @IdoTraini git is already in this path C:\Program Files\Git. Shall I reinstall it to the main C directory to make it work anywhere? It only works with me through Git Bash.

Answer (score 0):

To run ssh on windows, you need to download msysgit from [msysgit project page](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit) and copy the `ssh.exe` file from `msysgit/bin` folder to `C:\Program Files\Git\bin`.

Now try again `vagrant ssh` from cmd, git cmd or git bash.

Note: if you prefer, you can include the `msysgit/bin` to `path`, or copy all the content of `msysgit/bin` to `git/bin`.